# Slow build react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have created React apps.when I try to build react project using "npm run build" command from terminal,it takes more than 15 minutes to build project.Can any one advise what is the actual problem of this ???

Comment: What are your computer specs? This very much depends on your CPU, and 15 minutes doesn't sound unreasonable with a "slow PC"

Comment: Could you provide info of your pc spec? What version of node and npm are u using?

Comment: 4 GB RAM,dual core processor and the node version is 12.16.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It creates build for production, so it invoke some optimizations
If you want build your app faster you can build with development enviroment without optimizations
For this you can change mode parameter on **mode: 'development'** in your webpack config

Comment: where can i find webpack config file in my project ???